# Doesn't change the Bizcharts Colour

Tags: css, reactjs, bizcharts

I used this [bizchart](https://bizcharts.net/product/bizcharts/demo/11) in my react project, any one know how to change green and blue colour in this chart?

```
import React from "react";
    import {
      G2,
      Chart,
      Geom,
      Axis,
      Tooltip,
      Coord,
      Label,
      Legend,
      View,
      Guide,
      Shape,
      Facet,
      Util
    } from "bizcharts";
    import DataSet from "@antv/data-set";

    class Areanull extends React.Component {
      render() {
        var data = [
          {
            year: "1986",
            ACME: 162,
            Compitor: 42
          },
          {
            year: "1987",
            ACME: 134,
            Compitor: 54
          },
          {
            year: "1988",
            ACME: 116,
            Compitor: 26
          },
          {
            year: "1989",
            ACME: 122,
            Compitor: 32
          },
          {
            year: "1990",
            ACME: 178,
            Compitor: 68
          },
          {
            year: "1991",
            ACME: 144,
            Compitor: 54
          },
          {
            year: "1992",
            ACME: 125,
            Compitor: 35
          },
          {
            year: "1993",
            ACME: 176,
            Compitor: 66
          },
          {
            year: "1994",
            ACME: 156
          },
          {
            year: "1995",
            ACME: 195
          },
          {
            year: "1996",
            ACME: 215
          },
          {
            year: "1997",
            ACME: 176,
            Compitor: 36
          },
          {
            year: "1998",
            ACME: 167,
            Compitor: 47
          },
          {
            year: "1999",
            ACME: 142
          },
          {
            year: "2000",
            ACME: 117
          },
          {
            year: "2001",
            ACME: 113,
            Compitor: 23
          },
          {
            year: "2002",
            ACME: 132
          },
          {
            year: "2003",
            ACME: 146,
            Compitor: 46
          },
          {
            year: "2004",
            ACME: 169,
            Compitor: 59
          },
          {
            year: "2005",
            ACME: 184,
            Compitor: 44
          }
        ];
        var dv = new DataSet.View().source(data);
        dv.transform({
          type: "fold",
          fields: ["ACME", "Compitor"],
          key: "type",
          value: "value"
        });
        const scale = {
          value: {
            alias: "The Share Price in Dollars",
            formatter: function(val) {
              return "$" + val;
            }
          },
          year: {
            range: [0, 1]
          }
        };
        return (
          <div>
            <Chart
              data={dv}
              padding={"auto"}
              scale={scale}
              forceFit
            >
              <Tooltip crosshairs />
              <Axis />
              <Legend />
              <Geom type="area" position="year*value" color="type" shape="smooth" />
              <Geom
                type="line"
                position="year*value"
                color="type"
                shape="smooth"
                size={2}
              />
            </Chart>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Areanull />, mountNode)
```

Comment: Just change the color prop to the **Geom** Comp to whatever color you want to set to. e.g. `<Geom color="red"/>` 

If you want to mutate the color put that color into state of the component.

Comment: @Jawadulhassan Hi. I already tied it, but not working

Comment: Yeah you are right, there is some issue with the library. I am able to change the color but the colors are arbitrary in their painting. There are already some existing issues raised on github, having to do with it's coloring.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows how to change the color on bizchart, you only need to introduce your new colors under the "color" attribute

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Chart, LineAdvance } from 'bizcharts';

const data = [
    {
        month: "Jan",
        city: "Tokyo",
        temperature: 7
    },
    {
        month: "Jan",
        city: "London",
        temperature: 3.9
    },
    {
        month: "Feb",
        city: "Tokyo",
        temperature: 13
    },
    {
        month: "Feb",
        city: "London",
        temperature: 4.2
    },
    {
        month: "Mar",
        city: "Tokyo",
        temperature: 16.5
    },
    {
        month: "Mar",
        city: "London",
        temperature: 5.7
    },
];

function Demo() {
    return <Chart padding={[10, 20, 50, 40]} autoFit height={300} data={data} >
        <LineAdvance
            shape="smooth"
            point
            area
            position="month*temperature"
            color={"city",["red","#5225ab"]}
        />
    </Chart>
}


ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

The color Prop of the Geom component also accepts an array like so `[keyOnWichTheColorDepends, (key) => color]`.
So it your exemple it could be similar to below:

```
import React from "react";
    import {
      G2,
      Chart,
      Geom,
      Axis,
      Tooltip,
      Coord,
      Label,
      Legend,
      View,
      Guide,
      Shape,
      Facet,
      Util
    } from "bizcharts";
    import DataSet from "@antv/data-set";

    class Areanull extends React.Component {
      render() {
        var data = [
          {
            year: "1986",
            ACME: 162,
            Compitor: 42
          },
          {
            year: "1987",
            ACME: 134,
            Compitor: 54
          },
          {
            year: "1988",
            ACME: 116,
            Compitor: 26
          },
          {
            year: "1989",
            ACME: 122,
            Compitor: 32
          },
          {
            year: "1990",
            ACME: 178,
            Compitor: 68
          },
          {
            year: "1991",
            ACME: 144,
            Compitor: 54
          },
          {
            year: "1992",
            ACME: 125,
            Compitor: 35
          },
          {
            year: "1993",
            ACME: 176,
            Compitor: 66
          },
          {
            year: "1994",
            ACME: 156
          },
          {
            year: "1995",
            ACME: 195
          },
          {
            year: "1996",
            ACME: 215
          },
          {
            year: "1997",
            ACME: 176,
            Compitor: 36
          },
          {
            year: "1998",
            ACME: 167,
            Compitor: 47
          },
          {
            year: "1999",
            ACME: 142
          },
          {
            year: "2000",
            ACME: 117
          },
          {
            year: "2001",
            ACME: 113,
            Compitor: 23
          },
          {
            year: "2002",
            ACME: 132
          },
          {
            year: "2003",
            ACME: 146,
            Compitor: 46
          },
          {
            year: "2004",
            ACME: 169,
            Compitor: 59
          },
          {
            year: "2005",
            ACME: 184,
            Compitor: 44
          }
        ];
        var dv = new DataSet.View().source(data);
        dv.transform({
          type: "fold",
          fields: ["ACME", "Compitor"],
          key: "type",
          value: "value"
        });
        const scale = {
          value: {
            alias: "The Share Price in Dollars",
            formatter: function(val) {
              return "$" + val;
            }
          },
          year: {
            range: [0, 1]
          }
        };
        return (
          <div>
            <Chart
              data={dv}
              padding={"auto"}
              scale={scale}
              forceFit
            >
              <Tooltip crosshairs />
              <Axis />
              <Legend />
              <Geom type="area" position="year*value" color="type" shape="smooth" />
              <Geom
                type="line"
                position="year*value"
                color={["type", (type) => type === 'foo' ? 'red' : 'blue']}
                shape="smooth"
                size={2}
              />
            </Chart>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Areanull />, mountNode)
```